# Installing Ioncube (Dreamhost)

Tags: dreamhost, whmcs

I’m looking to using WHMCS to facilitate services we provide.

Now, I am having serious difficulty installing Ioncube, which is required to use WHMCS.

Can anyone provide me with a (easy to follow) tutorial/guide on how to get this installed Ioncube? I’ve tried both the tutorial provided by [Dreamhost](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214897027-Enabling-ionCube-Loader) and [WHMCS’ instructions](https://docs.whmcs.com/Ioncube_Installation_Tutorial) but it still does not seem to be working.

My config is environment is as follows:

PHP Mode: 7.3 FastCGI
WHMCS directory: /home/[username]/[folder]/[folder]/[folder]/_whmcs (this path is mapped to a subdomain subdomain.domain.com)

Any help would be appreciated, as I’m at the point of pulling hair out

Comment: did you check with a phpinfo.php file as suggested by Dreamhost on the howto? What method did you use to install IonCube? Over FTP or SSH? Do you have an error message ?

Comment: yes, i had checked with a phpinfo file.  Also, WHMCS says it is not installed.

Additionally, i tried using both FTP and SSH, though i'm not a frequent SSH user so i guess i may be missing something.

I guess, well - i think, the problem i'm having is with the phprc file, where i need to add another  "zend_extension" entry (sorry, i should probably have included this in my initial question). Even killing all PHP processes doesnt do it.